# Deploying a JS/Python/PostgresQL app on AWS

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, deployment

I have, as title says, a JS/Python/PostgresQL app that I would like to deploy using AWS.  I feel as though I could figure out deployment of the 3 pieces as separate, discrete entities, but what I haven't been able to figure out/understand, is how the 3 pieces will communicate once they are live.

The site will be a lightly trafficked one where only I can add resources to the db. Additionally, what AWS services would you recommend for hosting each part?

Thanks kindly.  And please let me know if I can provide any more helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

One service that you can look at would be aws lightsail that can spin up your application and connect to your database and is designed for hosting such applications.

Another way would be to have your python app send request to an AWS lambda using api gateway and the lambda executes your SQL command and returns back the data. These are 2 ways one more service you can explore is AWS amplify that can do the same as well